# Python: Write data to a txt-file using cron

Tags: python, cron

I am trying to do the following tutorial in 
https://stackabuse.com/scheduling-jobs-with-python-crontab/

to write some data in a txt-file in Windows.

My main code looks like this:

```
#Main code
from crontab import CronTab

cron = CronTab(tab="""* * * * * command""")
job = cron.new(command = ' python append.py')
job.minute.every(1)

cron.write()
```

and the file that the code wants to read looks like this:

```
from datetime import datetime
myFile = open('append.txt', 'a')
myFile.write('\nAccessed on ' + str(datetime.now()))
```

When I run my main code nothing happens. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried using full path to your file instead? Like `/home/user/file.txt`?

Comment: I don't know Cron, but the first line in the link you provided says _"Cron is a software utility that allows us to schedule tasks on Unix-like systems._", and Windows is **not** a Unix-like operating system. Are you sure Cron is compatible with Windows?